# Rails Facebook Custom login button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ruby-on-rails-plugins, facebooker2

I'm using Facebooker2 plugin for Facebook integration in Rails. This is how I currently render Facebook login button:

```
fb_login_and_redirect("redirect_url", :text => "Login with Facebook", :scope => 'email,offline_access')
```

Instead of using standard Facebook button, I would like to use my own style.
What is the easiest way to do that?

Thanks,
Miha

Answer (score 0):

I haven't use facebooker2 plugin but koala.
Can you follow this episode and do it use many providers:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/304-omniauth-identity?view=asciicast